# Firebase Assistant: Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new at android developing. Here's my code that I copied on the firebase assistant

```
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class FirebaseDB {
    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnopshot){
            String value = dataSnopshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(Tag, "Value is: " + value);
        }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
           Log.w(Tag, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
       }
   });
}
```

I'm using android studio 2.3.3

My problem is that, the myRef.addValueEventListener became error though myRef is a DatabaseReference which inherit Query class. I tried `DatabaseReference myRef = new DatabaseReference();` still got me an error, also the `new ValueEventListener()`, `DataSnopshot dataSnopshot` and `DatabaseError error`, same also for the `Tag`

Here's for the build.gradle, and the firebase assistant

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Post a crash log

Comment: There's no crash log. It just automatically makes the code red for the errors which means error.

Comment: Did you setup correctly firebase in your project, in gradle?

Comment: yup, after that, I used the Firebase Assistant to connect, and it says there that Dependencies set up correctly

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a firebase and appcompat dependency issue.
`firebase 10.0.2` is very old now.
The latest version is

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2`

Also you buildtools version is 26, which conflicts with your targetsdk version 24

Comment: i updated my tools using sdk manager but i still got the same versions

Comment: how to update the firebase? i just replace 10.0.1 to 11.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your errors are caused by sdk tools and libraries conflicts in your gradle. So try to update your `support` libraries versions to latest which is currently `26.0.0-alpha1` or at least `25.3.1`.

For example `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

Then update your `firebase` dependencies to latest version `11.2.2`.

**Note:** after upgrading `firebase` libraries there are some new rules

- your `compileSdkVersion` must be `26` also upgrade your `targetSdkVersion` to 26
- inside your build gradle add path for your dependencies which are now directly available on `maven.google.com` like this:

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}`

For more see on: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/some-updates-to-apps-using-google-play.html

Comment: i updated my tools using sdk manager but still i get the same versions

Comment: how to update the firebase? i just change the 10.0.1 to 11.2.2, and got an error